# How to create a mesh using these points?

Tags: python, mesh

I have some points that enclose a surface and I am trying to use pygmsh to create a mesh between them.
More specifically, these points model a boat (seen from above).

I tried to do the following:

```
import pygmsh
with pygmsh.geo.Geometry() as geom:
    geom.add_polygon(
        [
           
        #Here I Included the list of points
            
        ],
        mesh_size=0.1,
    )
    mesh = geom.generate_mesh()
```

The kernel kept on running without compiling.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of your data nor any of the solution you have written which produces your problem. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.